# JMeter throws javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

Tags: java, apache, jmeter

I am getting the following alert, when recording http(s) requests with **Apache JMeter** using **HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder**.

I am running jmeter from behind a proxy server. Therefore i am using the following command line :
**jmeter.bat -H 192.168.10.1 -P 8012 -u my_user_name -a my_password**

my java version is **jdk1.6.0_45**

what is the problem here?

note: ip and port is dummy.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1822)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1004)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:494)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.updateSecureConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:232)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.layerProtocol(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:401)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.layerProtocol(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:840)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:647)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:517)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:240)
```

Comment: Not sure about issue here but an alternative is to try Blazemeter Chrome plugin for recording of scenario.

Comment: I ran jmeter again without a proxy server. Result is the same :( not working and throwing the same exception

Comment: are you facing issue while recording script or while executing it? are you recording it in GUI mode?

Comment: This exception is thrown while recording. In jmeter, i am using using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.

Comment: are you recording in GUI mode? Its confusing as in your question you said about using command line?

Comment: what do you mean by GUI mode? i just start jmeter from command line. i use jmeter itself from its gui